# How to pass variable inside method of MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I need to pass a variable to MongoDB query inside of the method, but I got the following errors:

```
org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader expected a string but found '?0'.
```

**Query**:

```
@Query(value = "{ $and: [ {'created_at': {$lt: ISODate(?0)} } ] }")
Stream<MyObject> findByCreatedAt(Instant createdAtTimeInterval);
```

**Calling repository**:

```
Instant nowTime = Instant.now();
myObjectRepo.findByCreatedAt( nowTime.minus( Duration.ofHours(2) ) );
```

Please help me how is the best way of the current condition.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {
            "{ '$addFields': { 'dateString': { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ', date: '$created'} } }  }",
            "{ '$match': { dateString: {$gte: ?0, $lt: ?1} , 'channel.account': ?2 }}" })
    List<XXX> findByCreatedBetweenByChannelAcount(String dateFrom,String dateTo,String originNumber);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.